# Старт анимации по достижению определённого класса

Tags: jquery, анимация, progress-bar

Приветствую.
Есть простая функция которая берёт значение атрибута и создаёт параметр ширины. Всё это дело анимируется через **transition-duration: 2s**, но по загрузке страницы.

```
jQuery(function() {
    $(".progress-bars .progress--bar").css("width", function(){
        return $(this).attr("data-length") + "%";
    });
});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как запускать анимацию по достижению секции с барами, например. То есть, когда пользователь доскроллит до класса **.progress-wrapper** или спустится к нему через якорь, только тогда сработает анимация заполнения бара.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно при скролле окна просто рассчитывать и сравнивать позиции, например так

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
       var wrapperTop = $('.progress-wrapper').offset().top;
       var windowBot =  $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height();
       if (windowBot > wrapperTop){
         //Ваша анимация
         $(this).off('scroll');
       }
});
```

Comment: Благодарю. Это то что мне было нужно.

Comment: А можно ли как-то изолировать эту функцию? Например, на странице где есть бары, всё отрабатывает как нужно, но на других страницах заданный класс не находится и всё засыпает ошибками **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined**.

Comment: @Idon'tknowhowithappened можно например так if ($(‘.progress-wrapper’).length)